# Hibernate file into intelij module

Tags: hql

Progect Structure -> module -> Add -> **Hibernate**
But this file dosen't appear in mine[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5dAi.jpg)

Comment: Without more information it's hard to say what the problem is. Where did you see those instructions? Are you using the community version of Intellij? From what I understand the community version doesn't have built in support forJPA

Comment: Yah , i using community version of intelij but my friend hibernate include project also perfectly worked in my version. Still i don't know why?